# Azure SQL Server - Messages only in english

Tags: sql-server, azure, message

Unfortunately, messages in Azure SQL Server are only available for `language_id = 1033`.

Does anybody know a workaround to get the message in German, or is it planned from Microsoft to support other languages for messages, other than English, in the future?

Best regards,
Artur

Comment: From development perspective I suggest you stick to English language (original language for SQL Server), as it will be easier to find information. You can use `SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE language_id = 1031` to translate messages manually if you need to.

Comment: Hi @Artur Mughrabi, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Alex, hi Leon. in sys.messages i only have entries for language_id = 1033. The database is running on Azure basic plan. I'm looking for a stored procedure or function which can catch an error. The message "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '%.*ls' with unique index '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls." should show up in german and also the params should be included in the german text.

I could create a SP to catch the message ID and do a lookup in my own message table, but how can i also show the param values?

Thanks in advance and greetings,
Artur

Comment: @ArturMughrabi that's could be a new question. I'm sorry that it's hard for me and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

**We can not change the default language for Azure SQL Server or get the message in German**. There's no button for this setting.

Ref these feedbacks:

1. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/6516849-i-am-having-a-hard-time-finding-the-language
2. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/13776000-choose-language-in-user-settings-but-only-one-lan

According this research, we couldn't get the message in German. We don't know if it is planned from Microsoft to support also other languages for messages than english in future. Azure SQL database product team never response these feedbacks. You can continue to vote them or post a new [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Microsoft provided some workarounds for language settings, it may be helpful:

**Our workaround**

You need to specify in every connection the default language that you need. You could change in two ways:

1. **Once the connection has been stablished using the** SET LANGUAGE
   'British English' See this URL:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx.

   - If you need to know **how many languages are supported and the

     definition** of them, execute the query [exec sp_helplanguage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187357.aspx)
   - Also, you have available other settings at connection level as SET
     DATEFORMAT or SET DATEFIRST.
2. **In terms of application**, you have the following parameter in the
   connection string called [Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) , adding this parameter in the
   connection string "data
   source=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;initial
   catalog=DDBBName;User
   ID=username;Password=ComplexPwd!;ConnectRetryCount=3;ConnectRetryInterval=10;Connection
   Timeout=30; **Language=British English**

HTH.